# Multiple drag functions on d3 force drag layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js

I have the following layout:

> [image]
>
> - **Gray side**: the main container (zoom, pan)
> - **White circles**: d3 nodes (`mousedown`, `mouseup`, `drag`)
> - **Red rectangles**: rectangles (`drag`, without container panning)

When dragging the red rectangles, I don't want to drag the main container too.

Also, when zooming, they should'n be affected.

I think that the issue is related to:

```
// Add rectangle for pan handlers
containerParent.append("rect")
    .attr("width", SVGWidth)
    .attr("height", SVGHeight)
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("pointer-events", "all");
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/m666wtv9/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By moving the code snippet from your post **before** appending `g` element containing starter elements, the issue is fixed:

```
...
// Add rectangle for pan handlers
containerParent.append("rect")
    .attr("width", SVGWidth)
    .attr("height", SVGHeight)
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("pointer-events", "all");


// Add starter elements and their container
var starterElmsParent = containerParent.append("g");
...
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/88gL4aks/